# GridLayoutManager item width wrap_content not working

Tags: android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am laying out views using GridLayoutManager which works fine. However I each item in the grid fills the whole width of the column which makes the view having lots of empty spaces hence I want to use wrap_content for the root view of items but its not working. There's still spaces left from the right side of the grid.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has been able to answer this, I will just outline what I did to sort it. I use ItemDecorator to fill the space between the columns

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer  until someone post a better one